# Error path is not of a legal form

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, open-source, libpng

I am trying to build libpng using visual studio. When building with vc90sp1 (Vs 2008), it works with no issues. I upgraded the project files to vc140 using visual studio and now when I build using msbuild, it gives me the 'path is not of a legal form' error.

I am calling msbuild from inside a Python script and using a subprocess. When I run msbuild directly on the command line, it works fine. Not sure what is wrong but I am passing all the necessary environment variables to my subprocess. The same piece of code works with vc140 build of another open source project I am working on. Here is the error:

```
09:17:00.233 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018: The "CL" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form. [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(String path) [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker..cctor() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.ComputeOutOfDateSources() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.Execute() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(253,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() [C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj]
09:17:00.234 MSBuild    INFO         Done Building Project "C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
09:17:00.235 MSBuild    INFO         Done Building Project "C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\libpng\libpng.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
09:17:00.268 MSBuild    INFO         Done Building Project "C:\libpng\build\obj\win64_vc140\libpng\build\projects\visualc140\vstudio.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I have no clue how to debug this and don't even know which path it is talking about when it says 'path is not of a legal form'. There is very limited help online as well.

I also opened a bug with MSFT recently but could not get a resolution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df065854-36e3-45da-9773-d8a6339b2745/msbuild-error-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form?forum=msbuild

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you share the content in the vcxproj file for the projects that works and does not work?